# WooCommerce: Add ability to search on tags when searching products whilst adding a order in the backend.

Tags: php, wordpress, search, woocommerce, tags

So I've been looking everywhere and even asked WooCommerce support, but I just can't find an answer.

There is a search form when you add an order as admin in the WooCommerce Backend (see screenshot). When you search in this field, you only search based on the productname.

I would like to be able to search on tags in this search field as well. Does anyone know how I could achieve this?

I've tried plugins. I've tried to add other suggestions in functions.php, but those where never fully ment for what I'm trying to achieve.

I really hope someone would like to help me out!

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: I have maid some search and explorations… The code is located in the woocommerce plugin folder at `includes/admin/meta-boxes/views/html-order-items.php` it's very spécial product search field (as you already know)… I don't see any available hooks to make changes on this search field, for now.

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec, thanks for looking into it! Mhh, that's disappointing. I really hoped there was a way around it. And you don't think it would be possible to change this search field for another search field? Like the one buyers use in frontend?

Comment: Mostly everything is possible. I have seen some hook in the code to add additional buttons… So you have to think your need in a different way… but this seems like a very high level development, meaning that if you are enough skilled, it will take some time and energy to get something like you want. After that, I agree that this search field is just a bit prehistoric. This is the same functionality than in product edit pages when you add "Linked products" for "Upsells" or "Cross-sells"…